# Graphing the equation only after the right answer is picked

Tags: plotting, graphics, scripting

I need the equation in the question to be graphed only after the right answer is picked

I'm using this form to write questions :

```
    QuestionObject["Find the distance between y=12/5*(x-3) and the point (3,-4)", 
 AssessmentFunction[{ 48/13 -> False,  41/13 -> True,  71/13 -> False,
     48/5 -> False}]]
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: `{dist, arg} = Minimize[{Sqrt[Total[({x, y} - {3, -4})^2]], y == 12/5*(x - 3)}, {x, y}]` shows that the distance is `20/13`

Answer (score 4):

[`AssessmentFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssessmentFunction.html) has an option to provide `"Explanation"` to each of the answers. However, they currently allow only text-based explanations (with head `String`). Luckily, there is an explicit `If` statement, which allows only string explanations. You can remove it and make the explanations be whatever expression you like.

```
Unprotect[QuestionObject];
QuestionObject /: MakeBoxes[expr_QuestionObject, form_] := 
  With[{boxes = 
     Function[MakeBoxes[#, form]][
       Catch[QuestionFramework`QuestionPanel@expr, 
        "QuestionObject"]] /. 
      HoldPattern[
        Head[QuestionFramework`Private`result$$["Explanation"]] === 
         String] -> True}, InterpretationBox[boxes, expr]];
Protect[QuestionObject];

(* Your explanation *)
expl = Show[Plot[12/5 (x - 3), {x, 0, 4}], Graphics[{Point[{3, -4}]}]];

(* Auxiliary function for creating answers *)
ans[corr_] := <|"Correct" -> corr, "Explanation" -> If[corr, expl, ""]|>;

QuestionObject["Find the distance between y=12/5*(x-3) and the point (3,-4)", 
  AssessmentFunction[{48/13 -> ans[False], 41/13 -> ans[True], 
    71/13 -> ans[False], 48/5 -> ans[False]}]]
```

#### Version 12.3

[image: Explanation]

#### Version 13.x

[image: Explanation]

Comment: thanks for your answer! but its not working, do you know why? I tried to run the same code you posted and the graph did not appear

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I was testinh in version 12.3. In version 13, however, question objects are wrapped in additional ``InterpretationBox``. I have changed my code to make it work also in version 13.